# Открытие activity с применением анимации

Tags: анимация, activity

В "Яндекс.Музыка", при прослушивании композиции, появляется мини-плеер внизу экрана. Если начать тянуть его вверх - будет появляться другая activity.

Как это можно реализовать?

К сожалению, отсутствует возможность опубликовать анимацию.

Comment: `BottomSheet` погуглите

Comment: Похоже, это именно оно. Спасибо.